# Getting zero descriptors after computing HOG

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to compute `HOG descriptors` for images to train `SVM`,
My images are 50*50 jpg.

My problem might be is that i converted all my images previously in the dataset from `.ppm` file extension to `.jpg` extensions by renaming each image file.

Even i cannot upload here on Stackoverflow a sample of my renamed `.ppm` to `.jpg` images, the parser says "This format is not supported".

But on the other hand this images i can preview them on my computer(`OS X`), i can load them by `OpenCV`, i can manipulate them and i can loop all over there pixels as normal images.

I believe that their is nothing wrong in my code since i tried different images and they did work.

```
MatOfFloat descriptors = new MatOfFloat();
MatOfPoint locations = new  MatOfPoint();
HOGDescriptor hog = new HOGDescriptor();

Mat img = Highgui.imread("/Desktop/11.jpg", Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

hog.compute(img, descriptors, new Size(50,50), new Size(8,8), locations);

System.out.println(descriptors);
// Result Mat [ 0*1*CV_32FC1, isCont=true, isSubmat=false, nativeObj=0x7ffe63c01190, dataAddr=0x0 ]
```

It is first time to deal with `.ppm` extensions so if anyone familiar with that i would really appreciate.

**EDIT:** I have uploaded one of my sample images [Here](http://www.filedropper.com/1_101)

**A side question:** When computing `HOG Descriptors` for an image should it be in grey color space to train `SVM` or it would be okay if i leave it as an `RGB`?